# What happens to carpet when the padding is not thoroughly fastened to the subfloor?

Tags: carpet

What happens when the pad is not stapled down correctly.  My pad had staples anywhere from 3in to 10in apart most were about 10in apart one section about 6ft long did not have any.

Answer (score 2):

Pad is fastened mostly to keep it in place while installing the carpet, and to keep edges from getting overlapped with slight movement. It's not a requirement for normal function.

Once the carpet is laid there's not really anywhere it can go, and staples wouldn't stop it if it wanted to.